# Ora-00935 error group nested too deeply

Tags: sql, oracle

The following sql query keeps throwing an error that group function is nested too deeply

```
select department_name 
from department 
where department_id in (select department_id 
                        from student  
                        group by department_id 
                        having count(student_id)=max(count(student_id)));
```

Can someone suggest how to correct this without making other table ??

Answer (score 1):

I do not see what the `in` buys you.  I find this easier to write and to follow with the calculation in the `from` clause:

```
select d.department_name
from (select s.department_id, count(*) as num_students,
             rank() over (order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from student s
      group by s.department_id
     ) s join
     department d
     on s.department_id = d.department_id
where seqnum = 1;
```

This also makes it easy to add the number of students in the most populous departments.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the MAX analytics function

```
SELECT department_name 
FROM department 
WHERE department_id IN
  ( SELECT
      department_id
    FROM
      ( SELECT
          department_id,
          COUNT(student_id) students,
          MAX(COUNT(student_id)) OVER () max_students
        FROM student  
        GROUP BY department_id 
      )
    WHERE students=max_students
  );
```

Not tested.

Or in Oracle 12c onwards you could use the `FECTH` clause

```
SELECT department_name 
FROM department 
WHERE department_id IN
  ( SELECT department_id
    FROM student  
    GROUP BY department_id 
    ORDER BY COUNT(student_id) DESC
    FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES
  );
```